# sumar atributos de una clase python

Tags: python

soy nuevo programando en python y estoy intentando sin éxito sumar varios atributos de una clase pero no encuentro la forma, siempre me tira error. Pongo el codigo con lo ultimo que se me ocurrió por si alguien me puede dar una mano. Reitero, soy nuevo, pude haber cometido muchos errores.

Gracias.

```
class pedido():
def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.preciocombo1 = 5
    self.preciocombo2= 7
    self.preciocombo3 = 8
    self.preciopostre = 2
def sumacombos(self,combo1,combo2,combo3,postre):
    suma = self.preciocombo1*combo1
    suma2 = self.preciocombo2*combo2
    suma3 = self.preciocombo3*combo3
    suma4 = self.preciopostre*postre
    total = suma + suma2 + suma3 + suma4
    return total

    

def seleccion(opcion):
if opcion == 1:
    pedido_nuevo = pedido
    combosimple = ingresar_entero("ingrese la cantidas del combo simple", "Debe ingresar solo numeros")
    combodoble = ingresar_entero("ingrese la cantidas del combo doble", "Debe ingresar solo numeros")
    combotriple = ingresar_entero("ingrese la cantidas del combo triple", "Debe ingresar solo numeros")
    comboposte = ingresar_entero("ingrese la cantidas de postres", "Debe ingresar solo numeros")
    print(pedido_nuevo.sumacombos(pedido_nuevo ,combosimple,combodoble,combotriple,comboposte))
```

Comment: Susto `pedido_nuevo = pedido` solo asigna la referencia del objeto `pedido`. Lo que debes hacer es instancia la clase así `pedido_nuevo = pedido()`. Por cierto, se recomienda que los nombres de clases empiecen por mayúscula para así diferenciarlas de las funciones

Answer (score 1):

Hay temas con el código y con el modelamiento. Partamos por el código. Nombres de clase comienzan con mayúsculas, y el `()` se puede omitir.

La forma pythonica es la siguiente:

```
class Pedido:
    preciocombo = [5, 7, 8, 2]

def __init__(self, c1, c2, c3, postre):
    self.cantidades = [c1, c2, c3, postre]

def sumacombos(self):
    return sum(cantidad * precio for cantidad, precio in zip(self.cantidades, self.preciocombo) )
```

Veamos el modelamiento: primero, debes distinguir los atributos de clase de aquellos de instancia. Los precios de los combos no son parte del pedido, por lo que no son atributos de instancia y no corresponde inicializarlos cada vez.

Tampoco son realmente atributos de la clase `pedido`, pero si lo convertimos a atributos de clase nos ahorramos una copia de los precios por cada pedido.

Los atributos de clase se inicializan fuera de cualquier método:

```
class Pedido:
    preciocombo = [5, 7, 8, 2]
```

Segundo: El pedido está mal modelado, pues no contiene ninguna información acerca del *pedido mismo*. Lo mínimo sería tener almacenado las cantidades de cada cosa. Así podrías luego listar todos los pedidos o calcular las ventas totales por combo.

Cambiamos la inicialización para recibir de inmediato las cantidades solicitadas

```
def __init__(self, c1, c2, c3, postre):
    self.cantidades = [c1, c2, c3, postre]
```

Usar variables con número (`total1, total2, ...`) es mala práctica; para eso se inventaron las listas. El código te queda compacto y se auto-ajusta a cualquier tamaño de pedido.

Teniendo una lista simplifica todo. Por ejemplo, para calcular el valor de un pedido, sólo necesitamos recorrer cantidades y precios en paralelo, multiplicando y acumulando:

```
def sumacombos(self):
    return sum(cantidad * precio for cantidad, precio in zip(self.cantidades, self.preciocombo) )
```

Aquíe tenemos dos listas:

- `self.cantidades`, que es un atributo de instancia.
- `self.preciocombo`, que es un atributo de clase (compartido).

La función `zip()` iterador que toma ambas listas y va retornando una tupla con un elemento de cada lista. La tupla `(cantidad, precio)` la desempaco en el mismo `for`

```
for cantidad, precio in zip(self.cantidades, self.preciocombo)
```

para poder usar variables con nombre en lugar de la tupla con índices.

Finalmente, con `sum()` obtengo la suma de todos los `cantidad * precio` que se han ido generando durante la iteración.

#### Demo

```
class Pedido:
    preciocombo = [5, 7, 8, 2]

    def __init__(self, c1, c2, c3, postre):
        self.cantidades = [c1, c2, c3, postre]

    def sumacombos(self):
        return sum(cantidad * precio for cantidad, precio in zip(self.cantidades, self.preciocombo) )


pedido_nuevo = Pedido(1, 2, 3, 4)
print(pedido_nuevo.sumacombos())
```

produce:

```
51

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho por la excelente explicación.